# Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager interface with an Apache HTTP client, resulting in a security vulnerability

Tags: java, ssl, https, android-security, x509trustmanager

i had a code which app can access https, just like this :

```
public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            chain[0].checkValidity();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
        }
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return _AcceptedIssuers;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
        }

        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }
}
```

after that, google play console give me a notice :

Apache Trust Manager
Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager interface with an Apache HTTP client, resulting in a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Insecure Hostname Verifier
Your app is using an unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

is there something wrong with my code ??

Comment: Perhaps a better question is why you've eliminated hostname verification and almost all relevant certificate checking? This makes the code completely insecure for most scenarios.

Comment: If you've stubbed out so much of the verification, what security benefit are you looking to realize with SSL? Consider getting a proper SSL certificate for whatever server you're talking to, e.g. using the free letsencrypt.org service (no affiliation or specific endorsement)